# laptop black screen - and restarts even after holding down power off button

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop

My Asus laptop, windows 10 does the following:

I started it up (think after a windows update which may not have finished well) and was welcomed by a completely black screen (no Asus logo, no bios access, nothing), but I hear from the power on button, HDD and fan noise that the machine is working

I tried to:

- shut the laptop off by holding down the power button up to 30
  seconds, but as soon as I release the button, the laptop starts up
  again to the black screen
- drain the laptop of power and go at it again. Same problem
- connect an external monitor - no signal
- boot from a bootable usb drive, but as the laptop never shuts down, I
  cannot even access the boot menu

It is not easy to open this laptop and I lack the instruments. It is outside of warranty. If one of you has a magical solution, this would be very much appreciated

**Update**

After having left the computer several days without power and starting it up again, it worked. As I couldn't remove the battery without tools, I think this was the only way to shut it down completely. Thanks for all the comments

Comment: To access the BIOS/UEFI, power down, then hold the appropriate button (F2, F8 or other) *and keep holding it* while the computer is then powered up.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I tried that but I think the Laptop doesn't really power down but goes only in sleep mode, so BIOS cannot be accessed this way

Comment: If you hold the power key down for ~10 seconds, or unplug the laptop and remove battery, it *cannot* stay in sleep, which requires power.

Comment: does ( ctrl + alt + del ) Work ???

Comment: try to make the battery completely dead, then have a bootable windows 10 usb or disc ready, to repair the PC. Then plug in the USB and power on the laptop and try to enter the bios and boot from the usb> when the windows 10 "Install now " screen appears, click on "repair computer" in th bottom left corner of the screen.

Comment: and don't hold the power button for 30 seconds, that is way too long ....just press it and as soon as you hear the laptop shut off , remove your finger.

Comment: @Elmo thanks for your comments. As I couldn't remove the battery, I had to wait several days (as the computer shuts already down before having used 100% of battery) to make it completely dead. I think this is probably the reason that it worked again when I tried 1 week later. You can write an answer in this direction if you want. Otherwise I will answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the battery completely dead, then have a bootable windows 10 usb or disc ready, to repair the PC.

Then plug in the USB and power on the laptop and try to enter the bios and boot from the usb> when the windows 10 "Install now " screen appears, click on "repair computer" in the bottom left corner of the screen.